# setTimeout not working on my onlick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

i need run a function only 5 seconds after clicking the button.

the console show me this message:

> VM9200:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getId is not defined at :1:1

```js
function getId() {
  $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/perfil/perfil.php?cuit="+$("#cuit").val(), function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      $.each(result.data[i].perfil, function( index, value ) {
        var id = result.data[i].perfil.id;
        $("#idPerfil").val(id);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="btnBuscar" onclick="setTimeout('getId()', 5000);" type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" name="button">Buscar</button>
```

i prove this: `setTimeout(getId, 5000);` and this `setTimeout("getId();", 5000);` and this: `setTimeout('getId', 5000);`

but anything work

Comment: `getId()` needs to be declared under the window scope when you use an `on*` event attribute. I'm betting you've placed it under a document.ready handler instead. Also note you can improve the code by passing the function reference to the timeout: `setTimeout(getId, 50000);`

Comment: That code should work minus not having jQuery referenced. My guess is that is not your actual code and your actual code has a document ready wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#btnBuscar').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/perfil/perfil.php?cuit="+$("#cuit").val(), function(result){
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        $.each(result.data[i].perfil, function( index, value ) {
          var id = result.data[i].perfil.id;
          $("#idPerfil").val(id);
        });
      }
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnBuscar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center" name="button">Buscar</button>
```

Since you are `jQuery`, so I used **click** event of `jQuery`.

```
$('#btnBuscar').click(function(){});
```

I've used `setTimeout` inside `click` method & added the lines of code within that (rather than closing another function).

Comment: Please add a description of the answer you give. This isn't the first time I've seen you do this. Regurgitating an answer doesn't educate anyone.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. I added, but I'm thinking how to put.

Answer (score 2):

`getId()` needs to be declared under the window scope when you use an `on*` event attribute. I'm betting you've placed it under a document.ready handler instead.

Also note you can improve the code and avoid this problem by passing the function *reference* to the timeout and by using an unobtrusive event handler instead of the outdated `on*` attribute. Try this:

```js
function getId() {
  console.log('called!');

  // your AJAX logic here...
}

$(function() {
  $('#btnBuscar').click(function() {
    setTimeout(getId, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnBuscar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" name="button">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: Best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are - working example

```js
function getId() {
  alert('function');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnBuscar" onclick="setTimeout(getId, 3000);" type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" name="button">Buscar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout accepts a reference to a function as the first argument.
This can be the name of a function:

```
function explode(){
   console.log('called!');
}
setTimeout(explode, 5000);
```

A variable that refers to a function:

```
var explode = getId(){
   console.log('called!');
};
setTimeout(explode, 5000);
```

Or an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(getId(){
   console.log('called!');
}, 5000);
```

It is also possible to pass setTimeout a string of code for it to execute:

```
setTimeout("console.log('called!');", 5000);
```